# Angular JS and Web API 2 external authentication

Tags: cors, facebook-authentication, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to use Web API 2's build in external authentication with Angular JS being hosted on a different web-server? If so does anyone know of an example?

I'm struggling to get it working. The facebook request is giving me a CORS issue. I'm not sure what is going on.

My only guess is the redirect is coming from a different domain than the web api is hosted on. Which is what is doing the facebook configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You  can  enable CORS by  using  free  third  party  DLL just  follow this steps
1. Download Add refrence  of "owin cors"dll to  your  project
2.Add  one Class  file  in  your  Web api

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            ConfigureAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            app.UseWebApi(config);


        }
    }
3. Decorate your class  with 
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourNameSpaces.Startup))]
```